# Akka serialization-bindings too limited?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence, akka-remote-actor, akka-actor

Is is possible to further qualify the serialization-bindings?
The runtime type seems too limited.

e.g. I've got

```
trait PersistentExecutorProtocol[Payload] extends Serializable {
  sealed trait Event extends Serializable
  case class ToDo(value: Payload) extends Event
  case class Done(value: Long) extends Event
}
object AProtocolInstance extends PersistentExecutorProtocol[MyPayload]
object BProtocolInstance extends PersistentExecutorProtocol[OtherPayload]
```

I'm now unable to serialize `ToDo[MyPayload]` with a different serializer than `ToDo[OtherPayload]` (even in different Actors!), because their runtime class name is equal (`PersistentExecutorProtocol$ToDo`).

Am I missing something? -Introducing an `AProtocolClass` or making `PersistentExecutorProtocol` an `abstract class` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific Akka but is a result of how concepts in Scala (path dependent types) does not map 1:1 with what the JVM can do. The Scala compiler needs to encode such concepts in a way that the JVM can understand and this can cause loss of information (just like with type erasure for example).

Selecting a serializer based on an object happens at runtime and at that point the information available before the compiler has done its job is lost and only the JVM specific information is still available.

You could maybe figure out some way around this with `ClassTag`s etc. but the least risk of future grief is probably to declare Todo abstract and have the concrete subtypes inside of the concrete protocol instances which will allow you to bind different serialisers to the types.

You can se one way of doing that here: https://gist.github.com/johanandren/87fec0b627996a3f850513b81e0a8d66